# Excel VBA ignore error

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to get data from website [souq](http://www.uae.souq.com).

Code i am using to get data is:

```
des = Trim(Doc.getElementById("description-full").innerText)
```

but sometimes only short description available on site instead of full description, that is

```
des = Trim(Doc.getElementById("description-short").innerText)
```

i want "short" description of product only when "full description" is not available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim descr = ""
If Not Doc.getElementbyId("description-full") Is Nothing Then
    descr = Doc.getElementbyId("description-full").innerText
Else
    ' This assumes that html element with id `description-short` is always present on page 
    descr = Doc.getElementbyId("description-short").innerText
End If
```

Comment: you didn't handle errors in this, btw i am beginner and i learn "Nothing" from you, that is really helpful for my other VBA's.

Comment: As beginner you should learn that handling errors with `On Error Resume Next` is not the best approach. Try to check if the element exist on the page instead. The idea is: does the element exist? If yes call `innerText` on it. If no, then do nothing with it. Because how can we do something with element which doesn't exist at all? ... sure we can't.

Comment: thanks again, 
when i said i learn "Nothing" from you, that mean i learn "Nothing" TAG from you :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
On Error Resume Next
des = Trim(Doc.getElementById("description-full").innerText)

If des = "" Then
    des = Trim(Doc.getElementById("description-short").innerText)
End if
```

Comment: isn't that opposite of what OP asked for? This will store description-full in `des` and then if content is NOT empty it will overwrite it with short.
Should `<>` be replaced with `=`?